Disproof of an adjoint functor theorem?
I recently read about the adjoint functor theorem for locally presentable categories and am quite confused as there seems to be an easy counter-example. Would you like to help me find the error in my line of thought?

The "finitely presentable objects" in $R\textsf{-Mod}$ (i.e. whose covariant Hom-functors preserve filtered colimits) are precisely the finitely presented modules. See here for a proof.
$R\textsf{-Mod}$ is a locally finitely presentable category, as it is cocomplete and every module can be realized as filtered colimit of finitely presented modules via Lazard's construction
An adjoint functor theorem asserts that a functor between locally finitely presentable categories has a left adjoint if and only if it preserves (small) limits and filtered colimits.

Now for each module $M$, the Hom-functor $\text{Hom}(M,-):R\textsf{-Mod} \to \mathsf{Ab}$  has a left adjoint, namely $M\otimes_\mathbb{Z} (-)$, therefore, by (3), it must preserve filtered colimits. By (1) that would imply every module being finitely presented.

Your link for 3 doesn't say that.

The adjoint functor theorem does not say that your right adjoint will necessarily preserve filtered colimits, but only $\kappa$-filtered colimits for some possibily huge $\kappa$, and this makes the problem go away.

Thank you! I was not aware that the "accessibility degree" of the functor is not determined by the "accessibility degree" of the categories.
